# How do I increase the speed of a mob spawner in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a mob spawner killer for xp but it goes very slow. Is there anyway to increase the speed of the mob spawner?

Bedrock

Answer (score 1):

Try using the command `/gamerule randomTickSpeed 1200`.
You can change `1200` to whatever you want

Comment: Is the higher the number the faster the spawn rate or the opposite?

Comment: Probably bro. I'm just assuming that this command works

Comment: The higher the number the faster the game goes.